# Meaning of "dark-glass way"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Excerpted from [poetryfoundation.org](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/article/251704):

> And so, in its **dark-glass way**, “If—” reflects modern uncertainty after all. It’s a masterpiece of timing, of structure, of rhetoric (the genre that Yeats pointedly contrasted with poetry). But the more you read it, the more you hear a countersong beneath the assurance. In that long series of perfectly balanced clauses, you hear a mounting fear that the child won’t succeed. The sentence keeps building; the number of required conditions keeps growing. Maturity starts to seem like a very big “if.”

What is dark-glass way?

Comment: Could be referring to the phrase "**[through a glass darkly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_a_Glass_Darkly)**", but I'm not sure. Here's *[an explanation of the phrase on Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/through-a-glass-darkly)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dark-glass way** is a reference to the phrase **through a glass darkly** who's meaning is that we **can not see things clearly or perfectly**.

In your text, the meaning is explained by

> ...reflects modern uncertainty...

The original phrase was used in Paul's letter to the Corinthians.

The **glass** is a mirror, as in Alice's **Through the Looking Glass**. When a mirror becomes **dark** as with the mercury in antique mirrors, the reflected image **becomes obscured**.